# How to finish loading condition that a function to execute another function in jquery?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have the following script to add a new value to the array of my session variable, and show me the varible totally live session

```
(function ($) { 

    Drupal.behaviors.MyfunctionTheme = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {

     $('.add-music').click(function () {
         var songNew = JSON.stringify({
             title: $(this).attr('data-title'),
             artist: $(this).attr('data-artist'),
             mp3: $(this).attr('href')
         });
         var songIE = {json:songNew};
         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             data: songIE,
             datatype: 'json',
             async: true,
             cache: false
         });

         var session;
         $.ajaxSetup({cache: false})
         $.get('/getsession.php', function (data) {
             session = data;
             alert(session);
         });

     });

}}

})( jQuery );
```

the problem is that the POST shipping takes longer than the call GET ALERT then shows me the session variable not updated.

Is there a way to put an IF condition for shipping only when POST is complete return the response I GET?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, what you want do do is to use a callback - that is, a function that is called as soon as your POST ajax request returns.

Example:

```
(function ($) { 

    Drupal.behaviors.MyfunctionTheme = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {

     $('.add-music').click(function () {
         var songNew = JSON.stringify({
             title: $(this).attr('data-title'),
             artist: $(this).attr('data-artist'),
             mp3: $(this).attr('href')
         });
         var songIE = {json:songNew};
         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             data: songIE,
             datatype: 'json',
             async: true,
             cache: false                
         })
         .done(
              //this is the callback function, which will run when your POST request returns
            function(postData){
                //Make sure to test validity of the postData here before issuing the GET request
                var session;
                $.ajaxSetup({cache: false})
                $.get('/getsession.php', function (getData) {
                      session = getData;
                        alert(session);
                });

              }
         );

     });

}}

})( jQuery );
```

**Update** per Ian's good suggestion I've replaced the deprecated success() function with new done() syntax

**Update2** I've incorporated another great suggestion from radi8

Comment: Beat me to it. You might want to suggest the `.done()` method that's replacing the `success` option for `$.ajax` - `$.ajax({}).done(function () {});`

Comment: success: function(){...}); is depreciated so use done: function(){...});. Be sure to test to see if the returned values are valid before processing the GET